# computing Tor for flat cohomology

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $V^\bullet$ be a bounded complex of modules with free cohomology $H^q(V^\bullet)$.
I want to show that $V^\bullet \otimes V^\bullet [1]=0$ in $D^b$ which I think follows from shows that $Tor_{i}=0$ for all $i$. Via the spectral sequence $$Tor_{-p}(H^q(V^\bullet)\otimes V^\bullet [1]) \implies Tor_{-(p+q)}(V^\bullet\otimes V^\bullet[1])$$
I think its enough to show that $Tor_{-p}(H^q(V^\bullet)\otimes V^\bullet [1])=0$ which is true for all $p\neq 0$ because $H^q$ is flat by assumption for all $q$. But then $Tor_{0}(H^q(V^\bullet)\otimes V^\bullet [1])= Tor_{1}(H^q(V^\bullet),V^\bullet)=0$ is zero for the same reason?